# MPI double a map from a given GID and LID list

Tags: c++, dictionary, mpi, finite-element-analysis

I am working with a finite element code, where the nodes of the mesh are distributed according to a map (let us call it single_mesh_nodes) with local and global identifier.
I need to make a new map (let us call it double_mesh_nodes) which should include the double number of nodes. 
The double_mesh_nodes should be constructed taking as first part the single_mesh_nodes,
and afterwards starting again from the first node but assigning it new local and global identifiers. In other words, after the last global and local identifiers node (last_GID, and last_LID respectively) is reached, we should have again the first node but with a global identifier value of maximum GID +1, and a local identifier of maximum LID +1, and so on for the following nodes. 
As an example, if we had a mesh of 4 nodes, with single_mesh_nodes LIDs = 0, 1, 2, 3, and GIDs = 0, 3, 2, 1, the double_mesh_nodes should have 4+4 nodes with LIDs = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
and GIDs =  0, 3, 2, 1, 4, 7, 6, 5, that corresponds to the addition of the maximum GID number of the first 4 nodes to the single GIDs.

Comment: This is usually called p-element method.  Szabo did a lot of work on it in the 90s.  Has it not reached the commercial market?

Comment: the question isn't really about FEM but about handling data structures.  That said its really not clear what you are asking, what have you tried, where are you stuck?